# CombineLatest and return values

Tags: angular, typescript

In the first example, I have a component that calls this ClientService.
First we call loadClientMetrics, to populate the properties, but then take the properties and immediately send them into the calculateClientInsightsMetrics function. However I would like to change the service like in the second example to utilize the the properties in the service without having to pull them out just to pass them back in. Below is what I would like to do, however the combineLatest does not return before the return value, and undefined is returned. Can someone help me out? I'm looking to find a way to have the combineLatest finish before my return value is returned.

Main issue being I have a synchronous method that makes asynchronous calls.

```
  export class ClientService {

  private metrics = new BehaviorSubject<ClientMetrics>(undefined);
  public metrics$ = this.metrics.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), shareReplay(1));
  private clients = new BehaviorSubject<Client[]>(undefined);
  public clients$ = this.clients.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), shareReplay(1));
  private clientsBySHID = new BehaviorSubject<Client[]>(undefined);
  public clientsBySHID$ = this.clientsBySHID.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), shareReplay(1));
  
  ...
  
  public loadClientMetrics(forceReload: boolean = false) {
    this.loadMetrics(forceReload);
    this.loadClients(forceReload);
    this.loadClientsByShareholderID(forceReload);
  }
  
  ...
  
  public calculateClientInsightsMetrics(metrics: ClientMetrics[], clients: Client[], kycClients: Client[], clientFilter: string): ClientInsightsMetric[] {
      
      let metrics = new Array<ClientInsightsMetric>();
      
    ...Do stuff
    
    return metrics;
      
  }

}
```

```
   export class ClientService {

  private metrics = new BehaviorSubject<ClientMetrics>(undefined);
  public metrics$ = this.metrics.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), shareReplay(1));
  private clients = new BehaviorSubject<Client[]>(undefined);
  public clients$ = this.clients.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), shareReplay(1));
  private clientsBySHID = new BehaviorSubject<Client[]>(undefined);
  public clientsBySHID$ = this.clientsBySHID.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), shareReplay(1));
  
  ...
  
  public loadClientMetrics(forceReload: boolean = false) {
    this.loadMetrics(forceReload);
    this.loadClients(forceReload);
    this.loadClientsByShareholderID(forceReload);
  }
  
  ...
  
  public calculateClientInsightsMetrics(clientFilter: string): ClientInsightsMetric[] {
      
      let metrics = new Array<ClientInsightsMetric>();
      this.loadClientMetrics(false);

      combineLatest([
      this.metrics$,
      this.clients$,
      this.clientsBySHID$
    ]).subscribe(data => {
        
      ...Do stuff with the data[0], data[1], and data[2]
      
    });
    
    return metrics;
      
  }

}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. Do you want the subscribe callback to complete before executing `return metrics`?

Comment: Yes, basically that is my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the callback passed to `subscribe` (`data => { ....`) is not executed synchronously within `calculateClientInsightsMetrics`'s execution. It might look something like this:

1. Call `calculateClientInsightsMetrics`
2. Call `combineLatest` and pass a subscriber callback via `subscribe` to the returned observable. Note that none of the work defined in your subscriber callback is done yet.
3. Return `metrics` (not yet assigned to!)
4. Some non-zero time later, the subscription event occurs and `metrics` is assigned (too late) within the subscriber callback.

In other words, you need a way to force synchronous execution (check `combineLatest`'s documentation), or more likely you will need to "Promisify" your subscription (note this requires asynchronous execution):

```ts
public async calculateClientInsightsMetrics(clientFilter: string): ClientInsightsMetric[] {
      
    let metrics = new Array<ClientInsightsMetric>();
    this.loadClientMetrics(false);

    metrics = await new Promise(resolve => combineLatest([
      this.metrics$,
      this.clients$,
      this.clientsBySHID$
    ])
    .subscribe(data => {
      // do what you need to do and call resolve(), passing the value for metrics
      resolve(data);
    }));

    return metrics;
}
```

Note, this defeats the whole purpose of the subscription: you will only be able to use the first/next value passed to your subscriber callback.